# Best way to design a database for a bakery store?

Tags: database-design, application-design

I am building an application that will be used as a Sales Management system for a bakery store. I have built the following tables:

`Products` has a single row per product. This is a Master Data definition only. It has somethings like 'Pizza`.

`Ingredients` has rows like `Flour` and `Tomatoes` . These are raw input materials required to prepare different products. The bakery store needs to keep track of how much the raw input materials cost.

`Product_Ingredients` describes what raw materials go in a final product. It could have something like `Pizza | Tomatoes` and `Pizza | Green Peppers`, `Cup Cake|Strawberry Mix` etc.

My question is this:
As a final product, the bakery offers `Strawberry Mix` for sale.
But in the database it is considered as an ingredient.
I can also add it as a separate `Product` but here is what makes this case complicated:

In case the bakery runs out of Strawberry mix, they want to grab one from the shelf and convert it from a final product into an ingredient that will be used to make other final products.

How can I go about turning this logic into database objects that make sense?

Here is what I tried:
I created an `Inventory` table that has a row for each raw material.

When the bakery buys raw material, these are stored in the inventory table normally.
The strawbery mix is inserted into the `Products` table to get the same treatment as the other final products (sale / discount / tax, etc).

When the bakery staff want to use the mix from the shelf, they will have to "convert" it from final to raw material. Meaning, the application will mark the product unfit for sale, and will also insert a row in the `inventory` table.

My solution has problems that can have ways around, but I wanted to know if there are better ways (as I am sure) of solving this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have an ingredient; let's call this "strawberry mix, packet, 100g". You also have a product; let's call this "strawberry mix". There is a `Product_Ingredients` row which maps the product "strawberry mix" to the ingredient "strawberry mix, packet, 100g" with a quantity of 1. No need to convert anything to anything.

Comment: This is so simple, it makes you wonder why didn't I think of that?